# PC-Lint How to exclude messages from include files?

Tags: lint, pc-lint

I am using PC lint for my C project. And I want to exclude all the messages related to include files. I have tried to add `+libh(*.h)` or `+libh(*core_cm4.h)` but I am still getting all the errors from include files. The only time I am not getting anything if I add `-w0` but I only want the info, warnings, and errors for all the source files.

Comment: Can you give examples of the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

`+libh` specifies header files that are to be treated as library headers - but you still need to tell PC-Lint to ignore all errors in libraries.

That can be done with `-wlib=4 -wlib=0`.